# What stops electricity jumping from one part of a circuit to another part of a circuit in a CPU?

Tags: cpu

If electricity jumps then what prevents even a small charge of electricity jumping from one conductor to another conductor in a CPU where the distance between the conductors is 1000s of a fraction of a mm?

Comment: The dielectric between them prevents it.

Comment: OK. I understand that insulators stop the current jumping through the board to other conductors on the circuit but what stops the current jumping over the insulators? If you look at how lightning strikes it is never linear in a perfect straight line. It is always in a wonky line

Comment: **Electromigration** was encountered as semiconductor fabrication went to smaller scales - seems to differ from your enquiry involving insulators.

Comment: @AndyChr Low voltage stops it from arcing. Also arcing isn't the only way for charge to move. Leakage for example. Dies are also layered.

Comment: @AndyChr The dielectric (insulator) surrounds the conductive traces on all sides, including above and below them, so there's no "over" to jump through freely. It's just like a copper wire covered in plastic insulation, except that in an integrated circuit it's all made from silicon modified in different ways.

Comment: I believe this is why those insulators you see on power lines are made of discs - this increases the path along the surface of the insulator between the two conductors. Don't forget that air itself is just another dielectric with a breakdown voltage, just like glass or anything else. Of course, perhaps this is because these things are generally outdoors and may be covered in water that's not pure.

Comment: Are you asking why insulators don't conduct? It's because they don't have any (significant amount of) free charger carriers.

Answer (score 18):

Common insulation materials have around 20 kV per mm of dielectric breakdown. If you scale this down to a thousandth of a millimetre, the breakdown in the dielectric insulation occurs at about 20 volts. Of course, different materials are used inside a chip but, the principle is the same until you scale so far down that a phenomena called tunnelling takes over.